# Angular reactive from null value cast to string "null"

Tags: angular, typescript, types, null, angular-reactive-forms

I am writing a reactive form where some dropdown values have null as default, like so:

```
<div>
    <label>My Dropdown</label>
    <select formControlName="someId">
        <option [value]="null">Choose whatever</option>
        <option *ngFor="let data of dataArr" [value]="data.id">
            {{ data.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

With my form initialized like this:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
    //...
    someId: this.fb.control(null)
});
```

And patched with standard `patchValue(model)` function.

The problem is – when I choose "Choose whatever" option, this `null` value becomes `"null"` as string. My other logic relies on empty values being true `null` not strings. How can I avoid this?

If it's important, the model that I use to patch the form has `string` type for `someId`. Is that a factor?

Comment: Can you create an SSCCE on something like https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: @ExplosionPills no need, accepted answer works perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to use `[ngValue]`

See this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hmcwmf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)